# Getting error when importing from SSMS into Visual Studio (SSIS). (Some of the packages in the project use the Oracle connector)

Tags: oracle, ssis, attunity

I faced a problem when I tried to import some projects from SSMS into Visual Studio. I discovered I have the same issue with all projects using the Oracle connector. If the project uses the SQL Server connectors for included packages, everything works fine, and I can import the project.
I assume that I have a problem with the Oracle SSIS connector. [Value Does Not Fall Within Expected Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I2Za.png)

### **This is the text of the error:**

### TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services

Value does not fall within the expected range. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Error details

===================================

Value does not fall within the expected range. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Interop.ProjectInterop.ReferencePackage(Package package, String packageLocation)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Load(IDTSEvents events)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.get_Package()
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ImportProjectWizard.ImportProjectWizardTask.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__1()
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ImportProjectWizard.ImportProjectWizardTask.PerformStep(ActionName currentAction, StepCallback callback)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ImportProjectWizard.ImportProjectWizardTask.ImportProject()
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ImportProjectWizard.ImportProjectPage.OnSetActive()

---

I installed Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity 5.0 and SQL Server Integration Services Oracle Connector.
(The source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-ver16 ). It didn't fix my problem. I still get the same error. [Installed connectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNJ6l.png)

This is the list of the relevant programs that are installed on my machine:

MicrosoftSSISOracleConnector-SQL19-x64

Attunity 5.0 SSIS Ora Adapters X64_2019

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU18-GDR) (KB5021124) - 15.0.4280.7 (X64)

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019  (System Type: x64-based PC)
Version 16.11.26

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA580

SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62205.05200
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Integration Services   16.0.5035.3
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 16.0.5035.3

Comment: Please actually post the text of the error rather than a link.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Hey Nick, I have added the text of the error in the description.

Comment: Looks like a horrible non specific error. Here are some things to try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493090/how-to-fix-ssis-value-does-not-fall-within-expected-range seems like it maybe something to do with inconsistencies inside the source code (not your fault, a bug in SSIS)